# java.lang.NumberFormatException for input string ""

Tags: java, long-integer, numberformatexception

I am trying to take a string and convert it into a long how ever I keep getting the error mentioned above

```
public long[] stringToLongDecrypt()
{
    long ciphertext[] = new long[elements.length];
    for(int i=0; i<ciphertext.length; i++)
    {
        ciphertext[i] = Long.parseLong(elements[i].trim(), 16);
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's the correct behavior. What are you expecting from empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse, only a valid numbers, empty String `""` is not a valid number. So, you have to check it before parsing it. Otherwise, you will get `NumberFormatException`.

```
public long[] stringToLongDecrypt() {
    long ciphertext[] = new long[elements.length];
    for(int i=0; i<ciphertext.length; i++) {
       if(elements[i] != null && !elements[i].trim().isEmpty()) {
          ciphertext[i] = Long.parseLong(elements[i].trim(), 16);
       }
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long cannot parse input which is of String datatype.
Try using the following instead:

```
 Long.valueOf(elements[i].trim()).longValue();
```

Comment: No matter what you do, parse or valueOf, you cannot convert an empty string into a number.

Comment: @Lesya Have you tested it before posting?